# Failed to write run key value

Tags: wix, burn

I want to build one (and only one) `install.exe` which can install both 32bit - 64bit OS, detect .NET, and pre-install it.

I tried to use burn, but it failed, even the most simple bootstrapper didn't work!

I used bootstrapper and automatically generated in VS2010, and changed one and only one code:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="D:\WiX\SetupProject\TestBurn\TestBurn\PlanManagerPackage.msi" />
```

My PlanManagerPackage.msi did work. My OS is “Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0)”, and I ran install.exe with admin permission.

Here is the error log:

```
e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to write run key value.
e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to update resume mode.
e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to begin registration session.
e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to begin registration session in per-machine process.
e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to register bundle.
```

Is this a bug? If it is, is there any method that can help me? If not, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

This issue is caused by Virus protection applications stopping the installer from writing keys.

Temporarily disabling the virus checker (McAfee in my case) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find that failed key, and I got this:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce[{4ffab39b-d145-4886-8cea-40edb757baed}]["C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{4ffab39b-d145-4886-8cea-40edb757baed}\BootstrapperSetup.exe" /burn.log.append "C:\Users\YANGSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\My_Test_Application_20131018100141.log" /burn.runonce]

I googled around and I found this:

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Reopen-Burn-triggers-virus-checker-ID-3431068-td7175855.html